# Burning Forest game glitch after completing the main story line?

Tags: ps4, far-cry-4

I've completed the main story line, and have just taken on the Yogi and Reggie quest The Burning Forest.  You run through a burning forest, chasing Yogi and Reggie to get your gear back, and eventually meet them on a roof top and then grab your gear from within that same building.  I've done this four times now, and the mission does not complete.  I get my gear and the forest stops burning, but the quest music continues and I can't leave the area without the quest failing and starting over.  How do I get out of this quest?  I've tried quitting and losing my current status, but when I reload the game I'm in this quest again.  Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exiting the game *completely* seems to have reset something, and I was able to complete the mission.  Simply exiting to the main menu wasn't enough.

Comment: You should mark this as the answer for the question then.